# Python Web Scraping - Failed to extract a name list from the website

Tags: selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I failed to extract the first column "Name" from the website. Is there anyone who can help? The website address is: https://www.dianashippinginc.com/the-fleet/

'''

```
chromedriver_location = ""
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_location)
driver.get('https://www.dianashippinginc.com/fleet-employment-table/')

cookie_address = '//*[@id="ccc-notify-accept"]/span'
name_address = '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/span'

driver.find_element_by_xpath(cookie_address).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(name_address)
```

'''

Comment: also here you should present what have YOU tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import scrapy


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = [r'https://www.dianashippinginc.com/the-fleet/']

    def parse(self, response):
        names = response.xpath('//div[@class="fleet-vessels__table_cell--norm-btn"]/text()').getall()
        # Process the names list to be as you want (remove tab characters, ranking numbers etc.)
        yield names
```